# Remove comma from columns csv

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, php-5.3, php-5.5

I have the following code :

```
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header("Content-Type:application/csv;charset=UTF-8");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $sFileName . '";');
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Refresh:0");
    echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fwrite($output, "sep=;\n");
    fputcsv($output, array('Column1','Column2','Column3'), ";");
    foreach ($aExport as $value) {
        fputcsv($output, $value, ";");
    }
    fpassthru($output);
    fclose($output);
    exit;
```

In the csv, I get somme columns with comma like this :

```
Column1      "Column2"      "Column3"
  1             "2"            "3"
```

Is a way to delete this comma ? I don' understand why for specified columns this comma is show. Please help me. Thx in advance

Comment: I'm not sure of what is your problem, you're talking of which comma ? The separator you use here in your CSV seems to be a semicolon.

Comment: I speek about inverted commas

Comment: I tried your code, it generated me a CSV without any quotes ("inverted commas"), and when loaded into my spreadsheet software (LibreOffice Calc), it doesn't have any quotes in it. It may be a configuration issue from your spreadsheet software ? Also, bear in mind that the "sep=" metadata is MSExcel-specific.